# Why does this box-shadow create a border effect?

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain *why* this box-shadow is adding such a border/underline underneath the heading element?

Is it a matter of enabling height mutability with inline-block, altering height to 50px, then only spanning the box-shadow with the coded parameters? Seems like this is what's happening, but I'm still having difficulty wrapping my head around the concept.

Thanks for your time and help..

```css
.heading {
  box-shadow: 0 26px 0 -23px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The fourth property of [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) is *spread radius*, which effectively sizes the shadow compared to the element itself. By setting a negative value, it is reduced by 23px from each side.

The second property is the y-axis offset, so the shadow is lowered by that amount.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `box-shadow: 0 26px 0 #000` makes a same size of the heading text.

And the last number `-23px` reduces the shadow from the top, left, right, and bottom **23px**.

You can check how it works by editing the 4th number. If you set it as a positive number, the `box-shadow` increases.

Answer (score 0):

Note the effect of animating the 4th `box-shadow` parameter:

```css
@keyframes k {
  0% { box-shadow: 0 26px 0 23px #000; }
  100% { box-shadow: 0 26px 0 -23px #000; }
}

.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  
  animation-name: k;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
```

It becomes clear that the box-shadow resembles a line partially because it is being occluded by the heading itself.

In my opinion a "default" box-shadow is something like a black, 3px-wide line around the content:

```css
.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
```

We can animate from this "default" box-shadow to yours, to see how your parameters have modified the appearance:

```css
@keyframes k {
  0% { box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #000; }
  100% { box-shadow: 0 26px 0 -23px #000; }
}

.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  
  animation-name: k;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
```

Comment: Even if the `box-shadow` isn't being occluded by the `background-color` of the heading, it resembles a line, because it has only 6-pixel height.

Comment: Certainly! This is why I worded myself the way I did. I think some important insight for the OP is the realization that box-shadows (unless using `inset`) will never render within the content-box.

Comment: @permalik wanted the **reason**, not **animation**, so describing the reason is important than animation.

Comment: @SatoTakeru I'm not sure I follow you - the animation can help to understand the reason, no?